# localizing raw resources in android app

Tags: java, android, localization

I want to serve local language content in my app. I am reading a .txt file in res/raw folder using FileReader (Buffered one). I have read that Android can automatically translate text for values/strings.xml file.

Is the same possible for raw text files. I am looking for minimal code changes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Android does not automatically translate any files.

You as a developer can translate them and put the resources in [appropriately qualified](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) folders, like `values-en`, `values-fr` and so on.

These qualifiers work on all folders under `res`, including the `raw` folder.

No code changes are required, as Android will automatically pick the correct file upon runtime. However, you should always keep a copy in the default folder with no qualifications in case the app is run on a device for which you do not have content available.

Comment: oh! ok. That would mean I need to manually translate that raw text file in the language I want to support. I thought there would be some way by which I can get automatic translation depending upon the language set in user's device settings.