# How to support different languages with sound

Tags: android

Im creating a application that´s talking to the user, I want to support English to. I know how to do so with `strings`. But i dont know how to do it with sound, is it just do create a new folder called raw-eng? Then put the English sounds in there?

I have tried to create this folder but can´t get it to work when i change the language to English on my phone.

I have tried to search on devleoper.android.com but could not find a answer.. mabey you guys here could explain how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use workaround. Add to string resources names of files. And load string by id. String will contain name of localized sound.

**Edit**

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17326050/799799). I thought that you tried to use raw  and this is impossible :)

Comment: that sounds like an option, will try this. But don´t stop giving answer yet.. the more the marier :)

Comment: @user3356636 try to use raw + correct locale qualifiers

Answer (score 0):

You can put your files to *assets* folder to different folders names, for example, *sound_en*, *sound_ru*, *sound_fr*. To select current folder you can use

```
String currentLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

or add folder name as string to `res/valuse/strings` (as X90 told in previous answer)