# Setting localized video view uri in Android

Tags: java, android

I have localized versions of a video I want to play in a `VideoView` but I'm having some issues figuring out how to properly play the localized version.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17326050/1313268) tells me to localize a `raw` resource I should put the localized resources in `raw-es`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616187/1313268) tells me that to use `VideoView#setVideoUri` I should create a uri for it like this:

`Uri.parse("android.resource://${context.packageName}/${videoResId}")`

(The above is Kotlin string interpolation.)

I can't seem to find any information about how to create a uri for the localized version, though. The uri created always references the default raw resource.

I can always just put both of them in the `raw` folder under different names and add some if checks, but I'd like to do it the correct way if possible.